# How to drop rows by condition on string value in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

Consider a Pandas Dataframe like:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(url=['http://url1.com', 'http://www.url1.com', 'http://www.url2.com','http://www.url3.com','http://www.url1.com']))
>>> df
```

Giving:

```
                   url
0      http://url1.com
1  http://www.url1.com
2  http://www.url2.com
3  http://www.url3.com
4  http://www.url1.com
```

I want to remove all rows containing `url1.com` and `url2.com` to obtain dataframe result like:

```
                   url
0   http://ww.url3.com
```

I do this

```
domainToCheck = ('url1.com', 'url2.com')
goodUrl = df['url'].apply(lambda x : any(domain in x for domain in domainToCheck))
```

But this give me no result.

Any idea how to solve the above problem?

### Edit: Solution

```
import pandas as pd
import tldextract

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(url=['http://url1.com', 'http://www.url1.com','http://www.url2.com','http://www.url3.com','http://www.url1.com']))
domainToCheck = ['url1', 'url2']
s = df.url.map(lambda x : tldextract.extract(x).domain).isin(domainToCheck)
df = df[~s].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we checking `domain` , we should find the 100% match domain rather than use string contain . since the `subdomain` may contain the same key work as domain

```
import tldextract

s=df.url.map(lambda x : tldextract.extract(x).domain).isin(['url1','url2'])
Out[594]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: url, dtype: bool

df=df[~s]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) here.

```
df[~df.url.str.contains('|'.join(domainToCheck))]

                   url
3  http://www.url3.com
```

If you want to reset index use this

```
df[~df.url.str.contains('|'.join(domainToCheck))].reset_index(drop=True)

                   url
0  http://www.url3.com
```

Comment: I thinnk `'|'.join(domainToCheck)` is safer.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, agreed. Changed the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use, [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to create a boolean mask `m` and then you can filter the dataframe `df` using this boolean mask:

```
m = df['url'].str.contains('|'.join(domainToCheck))
df = df[~m].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
                   url
0  http://www.url3.com
```

Comment: I believe `ulr1` and `ulr2` are just dummies. your pattern will be hard to swallow for OP's actual data.

Comment: @QuangHoang Corrected.